# How can I get a List of doors if the scripts on each door execute after the main script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The main script is attached to empty gameobject. And this script fire first.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<List<DoorHori>> doorsLR = new List<List<DoorHori>>();
    public static void GetDoors(List<DoorHori> doorsLR)
    {
        doorsLR.AddRange(doorsLR);
    }

    private List<HoriDoorManager> Doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();

    private void Start()
    {
        var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
        foreach(var door in doors)
        {
            Doors.Add(door.GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>());
        }
    }
}
```

This script the second one is attached to each door and the Start in this script execute after the top script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class HoriDoorManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<DoorHori> doors = new List<DoorHori>();
    private bool doorLockState;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (transform.parent != null)
        {
            Transform parent = transform.parent;
            var children = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

            if(children != null)
            {
                foreach (Transform door in children)
                {
                    if (door.name == "Door_Left" || door.name == "Door_Right")
                        doors.Add(door.GetComponent<DoorHori>());
                }

                DoorsLockManager.GetDoors(doors);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        if (doorLockState == false)
        {
            if (doors != null)
            {
               for(int i =0; i < doors.Count; i++)
                {
                    doors[i].OpenDoor();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ChangeLockState(bool lockState)
    {
        doorLockState = lockState;
    }
}
```

The problem is that before it will add all the doors to the doorsLR List in the first script the first script will already execute his Start.

I want first getting all the doors from HoriDoorManager and only then to execute the Start in the DoorsLockManager script.

I don't want to use tags I want to get each two doors from HoriDoorManager add them to the doorsLR when it finished adding all the doors then start working with it in the DoorsLockManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code in your `HoriDoorManager` to `Awake` (instead of `Start`).  All of the `Awake` methods in your scene's components will all execute before any `Start` method is executed.

[Here is a further description of the order of events in each scene.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)